# Spring Integration: Using response from one call as one of the inputs to later calls

Tags: spring-integration

I'm working on an orchestration layer where using spring integration, I'm want to process the request as follows:

```
<int:recipient-list-router id="cfRequestRouter" input-channel="cfRequestChannel">
    <int:recipient channel="Op1RequestChannel"/> <!-- Calls Op1 Gateway -->
    <int:recipient channel="Op2RequestChannel"/> <!-- Calls Op2 Gateway -->
    <int:recipient channel="Op3RequestChannel"/> <!-- Calls Op3 Gateway -->             
    <int:recipient channel="AsyncOp4RequestChannel"/> <!-- Calls Op4 Gateway -->
</int:recipient-list-router>
```

The request is 1st sent to Op1RequestChannel, which in turn is sent to a Op1 to process the request.
After successful processing by Op1 Gateway, the original request is sent to Op2 Gateway. 
I have to use some of the information from the response received from Op2 Gateway 
and combine it with the original request received on cfRequestChannel and send it to AsyncOp4RequestChannel for further processing after the request is processed by  Op3 Gateway.

I tried the Claim Check pattern to store the response from Op2RequestChannel and have it stored as a response header returned on Op2 Gateway but not sure how to take the header from this response and pass it on to AsyncOp4RequestChannel.
Also, how can I do a claim check out and within a transformer to retrieve data to add as payload before sending it on to Op4 Gateway.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Update:

Message comes in on cfRequestChannel (the request is a combination of all fields required for each of the 4 flows)

--> call Op1 Flow (REST API call) to validate eligibility

--> On receiving Http 200, send to Op2 flow --> Op2 flow (REST API call) creates a unique Id on successful processing. If anything other than Http 200, send it back to client as error

--> If Op2 flow is successful, call Op3 flow (REST API call), which updates another system. The response contains status field which can have 2 values - Approved, Pending. If Approved, gather the unique Id from Op2 flow and few fields from original message and send to Op4 flow for logging. If Pending, use a generic message to call Op4 flow. If error occurs during Op3 flow, send back to client.

--> If Op3 flow is successful, make an asyc call to Op4 and return right away with success code to client

Answer (score 1):

If your AsyncOp4 is using not just the original message, but also the response from Op2, you will need to either use a content enricher to enrich or completely transform that message into a different one and then send the transformed message to AsyncOp4

Comment: Yes, I need to enrich the original message with the response from Op2 flow before I send to Op4 flow, but I also have to make another call to Op3 flow and only after parsing the data from Op3, I will know whether or not I have to use Op2 response. Op4 flow may not even be called in case of failures from Op2 or Op3 flows, in which case the error must be sent back to the client.

Comment: In that case, you will need to configure the Op3 and add a filter (to select only certain type of messages based on Op3's response). Or may be set something in the header of the message and use a header-value router. Also, rethink your entire orchestration and see if you can optimize or improve any of this. It seems too tightly coupled.

Comment: Ok thanks for the suggestion, I will re-evaluate the orchestration.

Answer (score 0):

Use an enricher to call the Op2 flow; the enricher can be used to add content to the payload and/or headers.

[See the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html#payload-enricher).

Comment: I will have to make another call to Op3 flow before I can make Op4 call, which will be fire and forget call. Op2 and Op3 are the main services that determine the result of this orchestration. Based on the response from Op3, I might have to extract data from the response of Op2 and send it to Op4 as an async call using an executor channel. Is using an enricher to call Op2 flow the best solution in this case?

Comment: The downstream topology is irrelevant - if you want to enhance data with the result from invoking some service then the enricher is the correct component.

Comment: Can you please help me understand how to make the call to Op3 flow if I use  an enricher to call Op2 flow? I have to parse the response from Op3 flow, and the depending on a value for one of the field, I will have to either enrich the original request with Op2 response or some other value.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question with a much clearer explanation of what you are trying to do.